# TSQL: Strange behavior using case statement

Tags: sql-server

I have a scenario wherein I have to update Customer table’s Billing_Start_Month column based on the Start_Month.

I have been given Start_Month value in an excel sheet along with customer name. To do so, I have created a temp table and inserted all CustomerName and Start_Month values. In excel sheet Start_Month values contain some other values also eg: (If Start_Month is any month like January, February etc then update Billing_Start_Month column as 1, 2 recpectively, but if Start_Month values contains values like 1,3,4,5,7 then we need to leave those records without updating Billing_Start_Month column of customer table). We have only 5 records in excel sheet which has Start_Month values like “1,3,4,5,7”.

Now I am updating Customer table’s Billing_Start_Month column using following query:

```
UPDATE Customer
SET Billing_Start_Month = CASE WHEN tmp.StartMonth = 'January' THEN 1
                               WHEN tmp.StartMonth = ‘February’ THEN 2
                          END
FROM #temp tmp
INNER JOIN Customer c
ON tmp.Customer = c.acc_name
```

But on executing this query I am getting Check Constraint fail error. And when I have deleted records of Start_Month values  containing “1,3,4,5,7” from temp table, the above query executed successfully.

Simillarly, in case I am not deleting  records of Start_Month values  containing “1,3,4,5,7” from temp table then I have to include another when part in case like this,

```
CASE WHEN tmp.StartMonth = 'January' THEN 1 
     WHEN tmp.StartMonth = ‘February’ THEN 2
     WHEN tmp.StartMonth = ‘1,3,4,5,7’ THEN 1235 –- any random value and not null
END
```

Please help me understanding this behavior of case statement. I am assuming that, When I am not including case ‘1,3,4,5,7’ in case statement the those 5 records are not considered in update statement.

Comment: As an aside, some of your quotes don't seem to be the right ones (`‘’ != ''`).

Comment: Also you might want to include an `ELSE` condition in case the month does not match either of the two choices.

Comment: Case statement is forcing me to include condition when {tmp.StartMonth  = ‘1,3,4,5,7’ } otherwise check constraint is being fired

Comment: Why mentioning January and again '1,3,4,5,7' ? can't you give month names..more over what the problem you are facing  and use the quotes '' not this  ``

Comment: @jonathan actually i have to update bill_month col with respective month like when 'January' then 1, when 'Feb' then 2, etc and i have to leave updates for the records '1,3,4,5,7'. But case statement is forcing me to include condition for records '1,3,4,5,7'

Comment: I believe if you include an `ELSE` condition it will eliminate the error, q.v. my query below.

Comment: Are you sure that this `WHEN tmp.StartMonth = ‘1,3,4,5,7’` is what you want? Shouldn't it be `tmp.StartMonth IN (1,3,4,5,7)`?

Comment: Please review the thoughtful answers given below, thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `UPDATE` statement tries to update all records. From your description, it sounds like there are some scenarios where none of your `CASE` conditions will yield anything, and you have no else. You could do `ELSE Billing_Start_Month` to simply yield the currenct valye for records that don't match the cases.

Alternatively, you could add a `WHERE` to your update, so as to only update the rows for which `Start_Month` is `January` or `February`.

Answer (score 4):

You can try using the following query.  I have added an `ELSE` condition to your `CASE` statement which simply uses the `Billing_Start_Month` in case the month be not January or February (in other words, it does not change the record in this case).

```
UPDATE Customer
SET Billing_Start_Month = CASE WHEN tmp.StartMonth = 'January' THEN 1
                               WHEN tmp.StartMonth = 'February' THEN 2
                               ELSE Billing_Start_Month
                          END
FROM #temp tmp
INNER JOIN Customer c
ON tmp.Customer = c.acc_name
```